# Chrome extension: sync localstorage with server api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm dealing with the conceptual problem that my Chrome browser extension needs to sync with a server in order to persist data in a database.
For my extension I want to save cleaned tab data to the server.

The problem with extensions is that there is no immediate visual clue as for when a network request succeeded or failed.
Therefore there needs to be a sort of syncing mechanism that backups data locally, in order to be synced in the background. If a backup failed, there should be an automatic sync starting when the service comes back online.

I have no prior experience with this scenario, but what I have in mind is:

- Store data to localstorage / chrome.storage.local until successful process by the server, then clean
- Repetitive checks on the client (however I would prefer not to have it done through setInterval).

Is there an alternative way to periodically check the localstorage in order to sync data to the server in case the remote server is unavailable for a period?

If there is a better (common) way for achieving desired result, I would like to hear it.

Comment: Maybe with websockets? Just a random thought. I guess it can be a tad overkill.

Comment: @MigMolRod It's not a bad idea but I think it's a bit overkill. I'd need too many connections and going through a service provider won't be worth the price.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the structure of the data being stored, you could probably get by with localStorage. Every time you make a change to a key locally (or add a new one), mark that key as "dirty" (i.e., unsynced). The next time you sync, you'll know which keys/values to sync.

For example, if your data is:

```
localStorage['tab1'] = '{...}'
localStorage['tab2'] = '{...}'
delete localStorage['tab3']
```

Store an additional meta key for your syncing mechanism:

```
localStorage['$syncinfo$'] = JSON.stringify({
  dirty: ['tab1', 'tab2', 'tab3']
})
```

Then when you go to sync (roughly):

```
for(const key of JSON.parse(localStorage['$syncinfo$']).dirty) {
  if(localStorage[key] !== undefined) {
    // sync updated (or new) value to server
    // remove key from dirty array
  } else {
    // remove deleted value from server
    // remove key from dirty array
  }
}
```

Of course, you'll want to handle errors and only update the dirty array when the server sync is successful, but this is a simple way to accomplish what you want, I hope :)

If you're looking for a solution that does this, you could try [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/), which is a localStorage-compatible API, coupled with a localForage driver that syncs data into a remote data store like [KVdb.io](https://kvdb.io), or another one with a compatible driver. *(Disclaimer KVdb.io is built by me.)*

Answer (score 1):

After some research I figured that `setTimeInterval` / `setTimeout` will do the job.

- Save cleaned tabs to chrome storage
- Make network request
- Clean up on success
- Mark as failed on error
- Check periodically for failed states
- Mark for cleanup on success
- Cleanup

The api should be adapted accordingly so it can handle multiple bundled requests to keep the amount of network requests low.